# Looking for a way to change the starting angle for AnyChart 2D Pie Chart in Oracle Apex V5

Tags: rotation, oracle-apex, pie-chart, anychart

The values for this 2d pie chart need to be displayed to the left and right of the chart. 
[The labels shown here are to the left and right and the chart is full sized! :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObE5e.png) 
[The labels shown here are above and below, the size of the chart is reduced! :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov83Y.png)

I'm using APEX V5.03 and using the standard 2d pie chart

```
   Select null link
   , FreeSpace Free
   , UsedSpace Used
   from Dashboard.DriveDetails
   where serverName = :P2_ServerName
   and   Drive      = :P2_DriveName
```

The Starting angle of the chart is at the 3 o'clock position and if the Drive is close to 50% full the values on the chart appear above and below the chart reducing the size of the chart.  If I move the chart to 12 o'clock it will have the same problem when the drive is almost empty or almost full.

Is there any way to adjust the starting angle dynamically - or to force the values to the left/right of the chart?

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there any way to adjust the starting angle dynamically - or to force the values to the left/right of the chart?

Unfortunately, it is not possible in the Flash version of AnyChart. 7.x versions allow changing starting angle dynamically.

However, to take advantage of 7.x you have to use APEX 4 or later and use plugin http://www.anychart.com/products/oracleapex/overview/

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to force the Labels to always be on the Left and Right? We are using APEX V5.03 - should I add a separate plug-in?